# Density function of a transformation

Tags: statistics

> A random variable $X$ has density $f_{X}(x)=2x$ ($0 < x <1$).
>   Find $f_{Y}(y)$ for $Y = X^{3}$.

How is the density function calculated for $y$ in this case? Are we simply
cubing $f_{x}(x)$

so the resultant would be something like $f_{Y}(y) = 8x^{3}$
($0< x^{3} <1$); that is,

$f_{Y}(y) = 8y$ ($0< y <1)$?

Comment: $P(Y < a) = P(X^3 < a ) = P(X < \sqrt[3]{a})$

Comment: right then take the derivative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest was to derive the density of the function of a RV with given density is to look at the cdf:
$$
F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=P(X^3<y)=P(X<\root 3 \of y)=F_X(\root 3 \of y)
$$

Then:
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_X(\root 3 \of y)
$$

Which is zero outside $(0,1)$ and in that interval:
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_X(\root 3 \of y)=\frac{d}{dy} \left[\root 3 \of y\right]^2=\frac{2} {3}y^{-1/3}
$$
Since for $x\in (0,1)$ we have $F_X(x)=x^2$.